# Android Keycodes for Symbols

Tags: android, methods, input, keycode, ime

I need some help developing my new custom built input method. I'm using InputConnection.sendKeyEvent to send new KeyEvents directly to applications. The problem is that I can't seem to find Keycodes for symbols (such as #$%*).

I tried sending KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT before sending KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEMICOLON to send a colon and it works, but it doesn't seem to work with numbers.

So my question is how do you get access to all the symbol keycodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below are the key codes::: [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

KEYCODE_POUND for #

KEYCODE_STAR for *

and you can get the key number of the event by using event.getNumber() like below.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

        Log.d("::"+keyCode,"::"+event.getNumber());
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to find keycodes for characters such as !$()%. Do I need their unicode references?

Comment: use onkeyDown code you will get the log for each key you press

Comment: The input method doesn't use "keys" per say. It's kind of like 8pen. So I'm only using sendKeyEvent from touch events on the screen. I'm thinking I have to check the character map and see which meta state must be active.

Answer (score 0):

There are two links: [link1](https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/keymaps_keyboard_input.html) and [link2](https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices.html)

'!' - keyKode :1, mortification(caps): 1,
'#'   keyKode :3, mortification(caps): 1,
and so on.

Hope it helps.